# Does Polkadot's Runtime/Wasm support any form of concurrency

Tags: runtime, wasm

I just want to confirm that Polkadot's Runtime does not support concurrency since it targets WebAssembly MVP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Polkadot Network does support concurrency in the form of Parachains.
But the runtime itself does not, so to say; Polkadot is a network of parallelly running chains, which themselves run serially.

That the runtime is serial is not primarily because it targets WASM.
Creating a semantic for deterministic parallel executing is really difficult in general. This is also the case for non-WASM execution.
It is currently not a high priority since the main scaling mechanism of Substrate happens through Parachains.

Comment: Thanks! The thing with the deterministic concurrent execution was another point I was thinking might be problematic to implement, so thanks for the confirmation.